# I used git reset --soft HEAD^ to hold my state, then did commit. So is it like each time, if I want to commit, I should use git reset --soft HEAD^ ?

Tags: git

Actually I was not sure so, I followed git amend approach everytime. Is it good practice ? If not Why git amend is not good ?

Comment: **Why** did you do this? What did you think it was accomplishing? Why didn't you just do a `git commit`? Why would you want to do this "every time"? It's not clear what you think you're gaining by using `git reset...` before committing each time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, using `git commit --amend` is **not** a good practice "every time". It merges your current changes with the previous commit's changes. You'll wind up with a single massive commit and no commit history what so ever. You should be making lots of small, granular changes so that you can actually track the evolution of features and introduction of bugs.

Using `git reset --soft HEAD^` is more or less identical in effect: You're moving the branch pointer to the previous commit but leaving the working directory state unchanged, then making a single large commit with all the changes you've introduced.

Using either command every time you commit will leave you with a single commit containing your entire project to date. There is absolutely no good reason to do this, and it is the completely wrong way of using version control.

Answer (score 3):

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

will effectively just wind back to a state prior to your last commit, but leave your changes in the index (as if you had done a git add, but not yet a git commit)

Don't `git commit --ammend` everytime, this will just keep amending your last commit. You want to keep your changes as change-sets that make sense.

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD^` and `git reset --soft HEAD~` are the **same thing**. `HEAD~` and `HEAD^` are synonyms.

Comment: mmm, not in posh-git, seems that posh-git doesn't like the Caret, just ignores it (hence it did nothing) I wonder if that's a powershell issue or a posh-git issue.

Comment: I'll edit my post to fix that.

Comment: Don't know, but caret is pretty important to navigating Git history. If your environment doesn't let you use it, you're missing out.